# Is it possible to create and use an array of MatIterators?

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, opencv

Example code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/video.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    Mat a = Mat::zeros(4,4,CV_8UC1);
    Mat b = Mat::zeros(4,4,CV_8UC1);

    MatIterator_<uchar> it[2];
    it[0] = a.begin<uchar>;
    it[1] = b.begin<uchar>;
}
```

I'm currently working on a project which has multiple related images, where making an array of the iterators simplifies the code down quite a lot and makes it easy to follow, which I would prefer to stick to.

Is it even possible to use an array of MatIterators? If so, how might I go about using them correctly.

I have a couple of other solutions to the problem, such as integrating the images together using colour channels and then using the one MatIterator for everything, or creating separate MatIterators for each individual image and going from there.

Currently using OpenCV 2.4 in the latest version of QT in Ubuntu 12.04 (updated and upgraded)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error on my behalf. Everything in the above code is correct, except that I forgot to include the brackets after the use of the pointers. The correct code is below:

```
int main()
{    
    Mat a = Mat::zeros(4,4,CV_8UC1);
    Mat b = Mat::zeros(4,4,CV_8UC1);

    MatIterator_<uchar> it[2];
    it[0] = a.begin<uchar>(); //<--------- the brackets that I forgot
    it[1] = b.begin<uchar>(); //<--------- same here
}
```

Sorry for such a mundane error.